# Can Apple provide the serial number for stolen Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, security

My Macbook Pro has been stolen and I do not have the serial number on hand. The police have requested the serial number to assist in locating the laptop. This is an important criminal case and they need the laptop as evidence.

I called Apple and they said they could not help me, but perhaps there was some miscommunication. I thought the registration information I entered when I initially activated the laptop would be sufficient for identification. I did not purchase a repair plan and the computer never required servicing.

Does Apple have this information based on that initial activation (I just did it again with my replacement laptop) or some other use of the device? The police/ the DA is willing to contact them as well, if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you registered the device then the serial number is recorded with your Apple ID at [**supportprofile.apple.com**](http://supportprofile.apple.com/).

Comment: That's the thing- neither laptop (stolen and replacement) shows up on my profile- but my Ipod Touch does. The process of activating a new computer- isn't that registration?

Comment: Does Apple have the copy of your sales receipt? They have mine linked to my email.